# Policy Gradient: Why would shuffling data cause performance dropping down?

Tags: python, neural-network, reinforcement-learning

[image]

The above is the average scores every 100 episodes when the agent runs on a `gym` environment `LunarLanderContinuous-v2`. the orange and blue lines are the results when agents feed transitions sequentially to the policy gradient algorithm (e.g., `ppo`), while the red line is the result when agents shuffle collected transitions before feeding them to the algorithm. I don't understand why simply shuffling data would make such a difference. To my best knowledge, neural networks assume input data is IID, so algorithms such as DQN shuffles the data(or random sample from the replay buffer) to break the correlation. But here shuffling data seems to make things worse, why would this happen?

Here's my project https://github.com/xlnwel/Distributed-Model-Free-RL/tree/master/dppo.

Each worker samples transitions until a certain amount of transitions are collected, and then computes gradients, sending gradients to the learner for updating weights, then repeat the above process. The code corresponding to shuffling data is at line 143 to line 150 in `worker.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the difference is between an on-policy (Policy-gradient) and off-policy method (DQN for e.g.). You cannot shuffle the collected data because after fitting each episode, the policy itself changes. When you collect new samples, they are on new policy. Whereas, in case of DQN, you update the q-value function of given state-action pair whereby you can still use random samples together and update them.

Comment: Hi @shunyo. Sorry that I'm not so sure if I take your answer right. In my implementation, I just shuffle the data collected before feeding them to the network, then the data is dropped and new data is collected again. I do not reuse any data here. My question is that neural networks assume the data is IID, so I shuffle the data to break the linearity, but it seems to make things worse, why would this happen?

Comment: Hi Sherwin, Sorry I did not fully understand your question. However, are you calculating the discounted reward every episode? I am using this policy gradient example (https://github.com/keon/policy-gradient/blob/master/pg.py), where you can find the discount_rewards function which discounts the rewards from the end of the episode to the beginning. After you calculate this, you can shuffle it, however, the result should be similar.